# The update of exchangelib remove the attribute 'localize' from EWSTimeZone

Tags: python, exchangelib

I was using an old version of the library exchangelib.
All was fine with my code until some users of my App start to have some issues.
Long story short, I had to install for me and the rest of us the last version of exchangelib
**exchangelib==4.7.2**

So my question is: how can I replace the method:
tz.localize(EWSDateTime.from_datetime(dt_start_time))
to filter the emails in my INBOX (or else)

Please find a small part of the code so it will be easier to read:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, Configuration, DELEGATE, FileAttachment
from exchangelib import EWSTimeZone, EWSDateTime
import datetime as dt

# fill in  with your Credentials
_outAcctName = ''
_pwd = ''
_subjectEmailToLookFor = ''

o_cred= Credentials(username = _outAcctName, password = _pwd)   
o_account = Account(credentials = o_cred, primary_smtp_address = _outAcctName, autodiscover = True, access_type = DELEGATE)
o_inbox = o_account.inbox

# Filtering
d_paramFilter = {}
d_paramFilter['subject__icontains'] = _subjectEmailToLookFor
dt_start_time = dt.datetime.strptime('2022-03-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
dt_end_time = dt.datetime.strptime( '2022-03-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
tz = EWSTimeZone.localzone()
try:
    tz_start =  tz.localize(EWSDateTime.from_datetime(dt_start_time))
    tz_end =    tz.localize(EWSDateTime.from_datetime(dt_end_time))
    d_paramFilter['datetime_received__range'] = (tz_start, tz_end)
except Exception as err:
    print(' ERROR 1: |{}|'.format(err))
try:
    o_emails = o_inbox.filter(**d_paramFilter)
except Exception as err:
    print(' ERROR 2: |{}|'.format(err))
```

I got now the error:
ERROR 1: |**'EWSTimeZone' object has no attribute 'localize'**|

I am aware of the following documentation. But that does not say what to use to have the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following :

```
tz_start =  EWSDateTime.from_datetime(dt_start_time).astimezone(tz)
tz_end =    EWSDateTime.from_datetime(dt_end_time).astimezone(tz)
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of exchangelib have an implementation of timezones that support directly assigning a timezone to a date:

```py
EWSDateTime(2017, 9, 5, 8, 30, tzinfo=EWSTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen'))
```

This is based on the new [zoneinfo module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in Python 3.9 and has the same syntax and guarantees.

Unrelated to the question, but you can simplify your code by calling `EWSDateTime.strptime()` directly:

```py
EWSDateTime.strptime("2022-03-13", "%Y-%m-%d")
```